# $k$-tuple conjecture.

Tags: number-theory, notation, conjectures

**This conjecture is false.** See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1215460/28555)

**Time is running out** Suggest notation for Steps 1 and 2. Earn the bonus.
**For each $k\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$.**
Step 1: Create a list $(1,1,1,1...,1)$ of length $k^2+2k$.

Step 2: For all n: $1< n \leq \pi(k)$, at index multiples of $p_n$, insert $p_n$ into the list. **Start with the greatest $p_n$ and work down.** This identifies composites with least prime factors less than $k$.

Within this list, when $1< n < (k+1)^2$, *all* $1$s represent primes, because if any are composite they would have prime factors $\leq p_{\pi(k)}$, but we have already accounted for all of those in Step 2. $1$s above that limit may represent primes or composites.

**Example** For $k=5$,

Steps 1 and 2 identify all composites having least prime factors $\leq5$. These lpf are persistent.
$(1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2$,
 $3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2$,
 $1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2)$

$\begin{array}{l}
 (1,2,3,2,5) \\
 (2,1,2,3,2) \\
 (1,2,1,2,3) \\
 (2,1,2,1,2) \\
 (3,2,1,2,5) \\
 (2,3,2,1,2) \\
 (1,2,3,2,5) \\
 (2,1,2,3,2) \\
 (1,2,1,2,3) \\
 (2,1,2,1,2) \\
 (3,2,1,2,5) \\
 (2,3,2,1,2) \\
\end{array}$

Above, we see that all unique Step 2 $k$-tuples are repeated. The tuple $(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)$ has the first encounter with a composite $(2,47,2,49,2)$. But looking ahead, we see that it identifies all primes at $(2,107,2,109,2)$, which led to the conjecture.

The conjecture: There are infinitely many $k$-tuple patterns when tuple index $\geq (k+3)$, where *all* $1$s represent primes.

Q: Are there better notations that I can use to improve this post?

Comment: You haven't defined any of your notation or terminology. As such I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. I'd guess this is why you're getting close votes saying your question is unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21226/discussion-between-daniel-and-fred-kline).

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example for small $k$. It sounds like you're doing a Sieve of Eratosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Deleted my answer, since I don't understand the question beyond the very basic example you gave. The gist of my answer was that I don't think your observations lead to new theorems about primes on short intervals, which is really just a comment.

Comment: I confess I've only read up to Step 2. When you say "index multiples of $n$," what do you mean by index? And when you say we're inserting $n$, *where* are we inserting $n$? According to step $1$ the list is entirely composed of $1$s, so wouldn't the phrase "only if it replaces a $1$" be superfluous? Or are we running some kind of loop after Step 1 in which Step 2 is repeated? And are we *replacing* numbers or *inserting* them? Those mean different things. Notation is not your problem here, your problem is that you're talking to *yourself*, not to *us*. Basic communication.

Comment: I know perfectly well what "multiples of $n$" means: I asked you point-blank what you meant by *index*; you avoided my question. Clearly you should be using the word integer, not index. After about half an hour of reading and rereading your cryptic instructions and comparing to the example, this is my best guess: (a) form a sequence of $k!$ terms (or $5!$ if $k<5$) in which the $i$th number is the smallest prime factor of $i$ that is $\le k$ or else is $1$ if there is none. (b) Now change all $1$s: the $1$ in position $i$ is changed to $i$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am honestly a bit angry and frustrated with you for making your writing needlessly unintelligible, for being unwilling or unable to write clearly and straightforwardly, and wasting my time because of it. No amount of bounty will help you if barely anyone understands your question. Don't blame it on "notation" either; I don't think you understand what that word means. Word choice and sentence structure $\ne$ symbol choices. Last request for clarification: in the statement of your conjecture, is $k$ fixed or not fixed? If it is fixed, then you should make the list infinite, not of length $k!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is limited by my inability to understand the question beyond the sieve described initially in an extended chat session. Since the OP now is asking about steps 1 and 2 perhaps the bar is low enough for me to answer.

**Step 1** is clear as currently written. Form a list of $k^2+2k$ ones.

**Step 2**. Modify the list from Step 1 as follows (by way of example, let $k = 5$). For the nth element of the list in Step 1, if n is a composite containing at least one factor less than k, replace the 1 by the lowest prime factor of n. If n is prime or a composite of primes $p> 5$ retain 1 as the nth element. This is done for each of the $k^2+2k$ elements of the list in Step 1. So in the case of the interval $[1,35]$ the list of 35 ones becomes:

$$\{1,2,3,2,5,2,1,2,3,2,1,...,2,5\}.$$

This is a complete step. What follows should be given a new heading in case there are questions about it.

This could have been done in one step. Many of the difficulties of this idea arise because it was originally expressed as Mathematica code.

**Step 3**. Divide the list into sublists of length 5. (The OP has done this above.)

OP observes that some of the sublists formed in this way are duplicates. Also *by design,* ones in the list in Step 2 correspond to primes or composites of primes greater than $k.$ That is, because a one occurred in the nth position in the original list, n a prime or composite of primes g.t. $k,$ it is no surprise that the ones appear where they do.

This is where I lose the thread of the idea. The conjecture as currently worded is difficult to understand

There is ample disussion of sieve techniques online$^1$ including some that have borne fruit. This particular approach does not seem likely to lead to new theorems about primes in short intervals but as I do not understand the idea beyond this, I can't speak to it.

$^1$ And in texts such as *An introduction to sieve methods and their applications.* London Mathematical Society Student Texts 66. Cambridge University Press. Cojocaru, Murty, (2005).

Comment: In step 2, instead of using primes we can use $n\leq k$. We sieve by replacing all multiples of $k,k-1,\dots,2$. This results in a list that contains all primes less than $k$, in multiplicity, and the remaining ones are identified as primes less than $k^2+2k$, because we use $k$ as the square root.$${}$$So, your use of _assigned_, while accurate, is not exact, because we have not factored any numbers to get their least primes. That is a side effect of the sieve. This is the crux of the conjecture and the reason that step 2 is so difficult to describe. _I have a full day, so be back tonight._

Comment: I have edited my answer. It is more or less my earlier answer (and anon's) but you have simplified the question so I think this reflects the process up through Step 2 accurately.