# Sublists Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, experimental-mathematics

The conjecture: For those $k$ that have a saturated sublist $a_{j}$, the first occurrence is: $$j \geq k+3.$$
A proof will imply Oppermann and will be a start to a pattern-based attack on the quadruplet-primes conjecture.

**Edit** This post contains counter-examples to [this conjecture.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1150474/28555)

Construct a list for an arbitrary $k\geq12$:
$$A=\left\lbrace \text{lpf}(n,k):1\leq n\leq\text{lcm}(1,2,...,k)\right\rbrace,$$

where$$\text{lpf}(n,k):=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1\hfill&\text{lpf}(n)>k\hfill\\
\text{lpf}(n)&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{array}
\right.,$$

is the least prime factor $\leq k$, or a placeholder (which marks the position of a totient).

Partition $A$ into sublists of size $k$:
$(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{\text{lcm}(1,2,...,k)/k}).$

For most $k,$ the construction results in a few saturated sublists (i.e., sublists that only contain least prime factors---no placeholders exist). For $k=15,$ no saturated sublists exist.

Q1: Is $k=15$ the only exception?
Q2: Is there a more precise lower limit?

**Edit** First occurrences of saturated sublists:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\textit{k} & \textit{j} & \textit{a$_j$}\hfill \\
12 & 183 & (5,2,3,2,11,2,7,2,3,2,5,2)\hfill \\
13 & 169 & (5,2,3,2,11,2,7,2,3,2,5,2,13)\hfill \\
14 & 157 & (5,2,3,2,11,2,7,2,3,2,5,2,13,2)\hfill \\
15 & - & \text{None}\hfill \\
16 & 591 & (3,2,7,2,5,2,3,2,11,2,13,2,3,2,5,2)\hfill \\
17 & 1211 & (3,2,7,2,5,2,3,2,13,2,11,2,3,2,5,2,7)\hfill \\
18 & 1547 & (17, 2, 3, 2, 13, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 11, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2)\hfill \\
19 & 3659 & (7, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 11, 2, 13, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 2, 3, 2, 19)\hfill \\
20 & 239 & (3, 2, 11, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 19, 2, 13, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 17, 2, 3, 2)\hfill \\
21 & 696 & (2, 11, 2, 13, 2, 3, 2, 17, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 19, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2)\hfill \\
22 & 5950 & (7, 2, 3, 2, 17, 2, 5, 2, 3, 2, 11, 2, 19, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 13, 2, 3, 2)\hfill \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: $k=401$ is also an exception.

Comment: Perhaps my methodology will become more evident if I write it this way: $k=4/01/2015$ is also an exception.

Comment: @GregMartin, I figured that out after I wrote Wow, so I added the length to show how incredible that answer is. Incidentally, 401 is a prime, so it can't be broken down into month and year.